# PHP Curl Get method

Tags: php, html, curl

I have create a form.html like this

```
<form action = "test.php" method = "POST">
     Name: <input type = "text" name = "domain" />
      <select name="domain_ext" class="inputAuto">
        <option value=".com">.com</option>
      </select>
     <input type = "submit" />
</form>
```

In test.php, i try to create a curl get method

```
$a = $REQUEST["domain"];
$b = $REQUEST["domain_ext"];

function httpGet($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();  

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    $output=curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}

echo httpGet("https://abc.php?domain=$a$b");
```

When i try to run the form.html, it didn't show any result. Can let the result display directly in form.html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give cURL a fully qualified url e.g. `http://www.example.com`

I added `http://` to `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'http://' . $url);`

I used `$_POST` rather than `$REQUEST`

I made a simple test script url.php that simply returns the get query values to test.
This is tested and functional:

script url on my local workstation: `http://127.0.0.1/misc/test.php`
which calls:  `http://127.0.0.1/misc/url.php`

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ERROR );
echo $_GET["domain"] . '.' . $_GET["domain_ext"];
?>
```

Then I combined the test.php and the form:

**This is the contents of test.php:**

```
<form action = "test.php" method = "post">
     Name: <input type = "text" name = "domain" />
      <select name="domain_ext" class="inputAuto">
        <option value=".com">.com</option>
      </select>
     <input type = "submit" />
</form>


<?php
error_reporting(E_ERROR );
$a = $_POST["domain"];
$b = $_POST["domain_ext"];

function httpGet($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();  
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'http://' . $url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
 //   $output =  curl_error($ch);
    $output .= curl_exec($ch);
//    $output .= var_export(curl_getinfo($ch),true);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}
echo httpGet("127.0.0.1/misc/url.php?domain=$a$b");

?>
```

**This is the result:**

[image]